# About NFC/Rfid: some trouble

Tags: android, nfc

I'm developing an APP for Android to read some NFC card (mifare 1k or 512).

Their application are not mission-critical: they will have inside only a number (different from card to card), e.g. 11001000015, 11001000027, etc.

Speaking with a technician that will code them, it says that these cards could be left in write/read mode, changing KeyA and KeyB from the standard (usually FF FF FF FF...) to another more complex.

In that manner, for a non-critical scope, a user that would be make some damage need to discover the KeyA and KeyB, useless for this.

My doubts are the following:

1) In the android APP, do I need to specify the new key(s) to only READ the tag? Or it is not important?

If answer to 1 is NO, do I need to specify a new key(s) only if I write an APP to WRITE/OVERWRITE the tag?

2) Is it possible to read the key, and verify is it right?

3) Tech says for me to use the 512. They are more compatible with more smartphone (S3, S4, S5), S4 for example doesn't read the 1k.

Comment: Why downvote, without an explain?

Comment: I think it is a legitimate question

Comment: In order to give a useful answer to your qustion, we would need to know what type of card/tag the "512" card is...

Answer (score 1):

The application could be just using the card's unique identifier or UID, as Mister Smith was saying. UIDs are set when the cards' chips are manufactured, so they are unique and unchangeable. But do not build a security application based on that, because UIDs are programmable in some devices.
UIDs can be read by all NFC phones, not only Samsungs. That's a big advantage, see below.

You could also choose to store the number inside the MIFARE memory. There's a lot of flexibility there regarding access control: you can for example  define a weak read key (KeyB = the default FF FF FF...) that can be stored in the phone's app and a strong write key KeyA you can keep secret if you want (you should read about *key derivation* anyway). By playing with the access control bits, you can read KeyB under certain conditions.

The problem is that only a few phones can read MIFARE cards: only those having the NFC chipset made by NXP, the owners of MIFARE technology. It does not depend on the memory size (btw, I am not aware of any MIFARE variant having 512 bytes).

Comment: Thank you, atm. Btw, they are membership card. So, I need to code inside a number, same printed on the card. For this, I cannot use the UIDs...

Answer (score 0):

I think the card ID can be read without the keys (`Tag.getId`). You would only need the keys to write or read the card content.

Comment: The number is not the ID. It's a number generated by me